# how to increase a input value via button click and also update this value in server site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I think, hopefully I will find the answer.
Thank you.****

Increase

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an 
attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical 
problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result,
 we can help with that. Please provide specific information about that attempt 
and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community 
and how we can help you, please start with the tour and read How 
to Ask and its linked [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can update the value of the input when clicking on a button. Hope this helps.

```js
const incrementValue = () => {
    let value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="number" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>
```